# Initialise an array of non-optional objects with a given size n where the object's initialiser may fail

Tags: arrays, swift, initialization

Long title but I think that summarises my problem best.

Given an integer *n*, I'd like to initialise an array with *at most n* objects.

The issue is that the objects in the array must not be nil, however, the constructor for the object type may fail (i.e. return `nil`).

There's two ways I came up with to solve that problem and I think there are more - is there a common, good-practice, well-known or better solution than the two below?

```swift
struct MyClass {
  init?() {
    // ...
    if (/* cond */) { return nil }
  }
}

// ...

// 1. solution
struct A {
  let arr: [MyClass]
  let n = 6

  init?() {
    let arr = (0..<n).map { _ in MyClass() }
    guard arr.allSatisfy({ $0 != nil }) else { return nil }
    self.arr = arr as! [MyClass] // At this point we can safely force-cast
  }
}

// 2. solution
struct A {
  let arr: [MyClass]
  let n = 6

  init() {
    self.arr = (0..<n).map { _ in MyClass() }.reduce(into: []) { segments, segment in
      if let segment = segment {
        segments.append(segment)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Sweeper Sorry, that's indeed unclear, I changed that part. If half of the initialiser calls fail, I want an array with n/2 elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [`compactMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2950916-compactmap).

```
self.arr = (0..<n).compactMap { _ in MyClass() }
```

`compactMap` takes a closure that returns an optional, and returns an array with all the nils filtered out. This should be exactly what you want, if I understood correctly.

Comment: Yep, exactly right! I felt like there had to be an existing swifty solution